# Scheduled Path Flow

Tags: visual-workflow

I have a record triggered flow in which should get triggered on create or update of opportunity. Requirement is whenever stageName is getting changed to "Closed Won" or stageName equals "Qualified" flow should trigger. There is also one scheduled path in this flow. I have mentioned two conditions as follows

when stageName is equal to "Closed Won" or stageName equals "Qualified". There is one email which gets triggered in action. Issue here I am facing is that even if I am not editing/updating any field of opportunity and trying to save a record whose stage is Closed Won or Qualified the record is entering scheduled path and email is getting triggered. Expectation is that flow should enter schedule path only when I am editing fields according to criteria mentioned above. Also can someone please help me to understand difference between all the four time source in scheduled paths? [image]

Comment: Can you try by selecting `Only when a record is updated to meet the condition requirements` option

Comment: Hi..thanks for suggestion...already chosen that option. expectation is that flow should not enter schedule path if I dont change any field and try to save but its entering.

Comment: Do you mean when you are not changing the stagename field and just clicking on edit button and saving it is going into scheduled path ?

Comment: Yes. I mean the same.

Comment: No this should not happen I have tried in my personal org it is working as expected. Can you check if something in apex trigger is updating it?

Comment: Can you try below formula in start condition `AND( OR(TEXT({!$Record.StageName})='Closed Won',TEXT({!$Record.StageName})='Qualification'),OR(ISNEW(), ISCHANGED({!$Record.StageName})))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have checked this internally with Product Team.In scheduled path any change in the date field placed in `Time Source`, Every time the field is changed it will reschedule. A reschedule does not require that the entry-criteria conditions transitioned from false-to-true.

As you have used `LastModified Date` in `Time Source` so when a record is edited the `LastModifiedDate` changes irrespective of any field change. So this is scheduling the path irrespective it is previously meets the condition or not.

You can try putting the following condition in place of `LastModifiedDate`

[image]